# Thevenins theorum calculating resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

Say I have a circuit consisting of many resistors, to get thevanins resistance is there a correct order to work them out in? For example if my circuit looked like this..

Would I do b//d then add that to a and e, then use what that gave me (call it f) and do f//c ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Would I do b//d then...

(1) By inspection, B is in *series* with the equivalent resistance of the remaining resistors.  Do you see why?

(2) Resistor C will not be a factor in the Thevenin resistance.  Do you see why?

Comment: I see why b is in series with the rest, so that means that it would be a d and e all in parallel with each other insetad, so I would do  e//d, then add it to a and add that to b?

Comment: And I ignore c because it is going across before any of them and there’s nothing between that and the voltage source?

Answer (score -1):

There is more to it than just combining resistors.

I would start at the left and determine the voltage and resistance looking left. Then progress to the right. Assuming the generator voltage is v.

At the generator the voltage and resistance would be:  v and 0

At c:  the voltage would be v and the resistance 0

At a and e: v and a+e

At d: v x d/(d+a+e) and d\(a+e)

At A and B: v x d/(d+a+e) and b+d\(a+e)

Note: the \ was written as a two characters to indicate in parallel. But shows as only one

Comment: Please do not give complete solutions to 'homework' type questions.